# What would happen if I used a cout statement as the condition for an if statement?

Tags: c++

So, my programming instructor asked me to try putting a cout-statement as the condition for an if-statement and see what happens. I tried it (just made a random code) and didn't notice anythimg special. Here's the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=1;
    int y=2022;
    if(cout<<"Covid")
    {
        cout << "\n Us \n";
        x=y;
        cout << x;
    }
}
```

The output is simply

```
Covid
Us
2022
```

What I don't understand is why this would be used. From my amateur understanding, even if I used an else-statement or any amount of else-if statements, they wouldn't run, since the condition for the if-statement is self-fulfilling. I could the simply write the whole code directly without using an if-statement. What then, could be the purpose of using an if-statement? Any general use?

Comment: If you `cout<<"Covid"` and the output is `Pakistan`, there seems to be something amiss.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out @Eljay ; I entered the wrong output. Been playing around with this for a while, so I copied the wrong one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prior to C++11, when you write `if(cout << "Covid")`, there is an implicit conversion to `void*`. This value is unspecified by the C++ standard, other than if the stream is in an error state, then `nullptr` is returned.

From C++11, the implicit conversion is to `bool`. `false` denotes the stream is in an error state, `true` otherwise.

Note that you must have imbued a very funky `iostream`-derived object indeed for the output to be "Pakistan" given your input!

Comment: The answer would be better if it discussed what is an error state and how a stream could get into an error state. I've never seen an _output_ stream in an error state before.

Comment: @MooingDuck: A punched card writer for example. A rarity in other words.

Comment: I entered the wrong output, sorry. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Less facetiously perhaps, you could `std::cout.rdbuf` to a file, and close the file.

Comment: Also, I understand that normally, the output stream will then return bool true. In what case would it be false? More specifically, what could cause the output stream to go into error state?

Comment: @MooingDuck -- `std::ofstream out; out << 3;`